# Could I also slice image resource in source code like xcassets?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, slice

[image]

I want to slice image on source code directly like the method to slice image on xcassets like the below picture.
I already figured out the way on google but I couldn't fine that.
If you know how that, please inform of me about that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change an image's Slicing through storyboard, it actually applies changes to `Contents.json` file corresponding the image.

Applying the changes you've made in the attached image, the following changes are applied to the file:

```
"resizing" : {
    "mode" : "9-part",
    "center" : {
        "mode" : "tile",
        "width" : 1,
        "height" : 1
    },
    "cap-insets" : {
        "bottom" : 27,
        "top" : 26,
        "right" : 21,
        "left" : 21
    }
}
```

You can apply the same changes programmatically by making use of the `UIImage` method [`resizableImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624102-resizableimage):

> Declaration:
>
> ```
> func resizableImage(withCapInsets capInsets: UIEdgeInsets, 
>    resizingMode: UIImage.ResizingMode) -> UIImage
> ```

Usage Example:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "example.png")

let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 2, bottom: 1, right: 2)
let imageWithInsets = image.resizableImage(withCapInsets: insets, resizingMode: .tile)
```